# Undefined method while fetching data from json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yelp

I tried to search with Yelp API using Yelp-Ruby gem. While I have some success with fetching results, sometimes I got an error like this:

*undefined method `image_url' for #*

I think the JSON returned does not have image_url or image_url = nil. But I don't know how to resolve it (I'm new to rails).

Here is my Search controller:

```
def search
  parameters = { term: params[:term], limit: 10}
  @response = Yelp.client.search('Melbourne', parameters)
render 'location_search/new'
```

end

And the corresponding results view:

```
<% @response.businesses.each do |business| %>
<div class="large-6 columns">
    <p><%= image_tag business.image_url %>
    <p style='color: white'><%= business.name %>
        <p style='color: white'><% business.categories.each do |category, name| %>
                                <%= name %> , 
                                <% end %>
    <p style='color: white'><%= business.rating %>
    <p style='color: white'><%= image_tag business.rating_img_url %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuong, try using the respond_to method to check if there really is a method/attribute `image_url` for business. Like this:

```
<% if business.respond_to?(:image_url) %>
  <p><%= image_tag business.image_url %></p>
<% end %>
```

In this case the image will be displayed only if the object really has the `image_url` method/attribute.